# How to access metadata when using "where" filter

Tags: jekyll

I've got a structured set of pages in a collection, and the structure looks something like this:

```
chapter1
   section1
   section2
   section3
chapter2
   section1
   section2
   section3
chapter3
   section1
   section2
   section3
```

Each is a separate page that renders its own permalink.

Say I'd like to make a link to chapter3/section1, how would I do this? I'd like to use the Liquid `where` filter, but this seems to give me the page *contents*, not the metadata.

```
{% assign section_post = site.chapters | where:"url","chapter3/section1" %}
{{ section_post }}
```

This gets me the proper page, but not the right content. If I were to write this in my layout, I get nothing:

```
<a href="{{ section_post.permalink }}">{{ section_post.title }}</a>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the metadata using a where filter? I've got a bunch of pages, so looping through them is super inefficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `where` expression returns all the objects **in an array** given a certain condition.

```
[#<Jekyll::Document _chapters/chapter3/section1 collection=chapters>]
```

In this case you are expecting that this list of objects just return a single item, so we can select that item with the [first](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#first) *liquid* tag (returns the first element of an array).

```
  {% assign ch3s1 = site.chapters |
  where:"id","/chapters/chapter3/section1" | first%} 

  title: {{ch3s1.title}} 
  <br>
  url: {{ch3s1.url}}
```

would output the desired section:

```
  title: Chapter 3 section 1
  url: /chapters/chapter3/section1
```

Comment: Perfect! Now I just need to go back and refactor all those for loops!